# "Comparison method violates its general contract" when I change the method of calculation

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I have trouble with understanding the logic behind this error, so i have a comparision method:

```
public int compareTo(osobnik obj) {
    if (this.fitness == -1 && obj.fitness==-1)
        return 0;
    if (this.fitness == -1)
        return 1;
    if (obj.fitness == -1)
        return -1;
    if (this.fitness > obj.fitness)
        return 1;
    if (this.fitness < obj.fitness)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

and until the fittnes is calculeted as absolut value of 1/(x^5 + x^4+3x^2+x-5) everything is fine (witha catch, that if the value of denominator is 0, then fittnes is -1). But if i change the function to 1/(x^5 + x^4-3x^2+x-5) (as a sign change next to 3x^2) i get the "Comparison method violates its general contract". Why? Why dose it work for one set of numbers and it dose not for the second?

---

[Solved]
As it turns out the Compare functions is all right. The criminal hides in 1/x turning to NaN.

Comment: Is `osobnik.fitness` a floating-point value? What is its range of values?

Comment: Yes, it is a floating-point.

Comment: What is its range of values?

Comment: Or, if it's simpler for you to answer, what is the range of your `x`?

Comment: for testing it's <0,100>, leter it will be set by the user. And sorry,i did't see that part about range.

Answer (score 0):

The range of your fitness function for the domain `<0,100>` includes your special-case value of -1. That's probably not your immediate problem, but definitely is *a* problem. If you want to support the case where there is "no fitness", use `-Double.MAX_VALUE` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. Then you won't need the special cases in your comparison function. The complicated comparison logic usually ends up breaking one of the essential properties of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity, and when these are broken, the sorting algorithms break with the exception you have seen.

With the special case sorted out as above, implement `compareTo` simply as

```
return Double.compare(this.fitness, obj.fitness);
```

(assuming `fitness` is a `double`).

Additionally, your choice of fitness function is suspicious because it:

1. has a singularity in the vicinity of `x = 1` of the worst possible kind, with extremely opposite left and right limits;
2. it quickly approaches zero for `x > 2`, so isn't a good discriminator for that range.

Comment: The situation is, that i seek the zero-crossing of the polinomial. So this -1 is the most important thing, and is there by design. And changing it all the way around (as the lowest fittnes is the best), is not an option, in my case.

Comment: I don't see the point about -1 being the most important thing. You treat it as a special value, whereas it is just one point in the continuum of values for your polynomial function. It looks like you are not focusing on the right aspect of the problem.

Comment: Also take note that the genetic algorithm, or whatever heuristic you use, will not be able to zero in on a singularity with  extremely opposite left and right limits. All such algorithms assume a continuous fitness function.

Comment: Hmmm.. ok, i want to know, when the function gets 0, and i want to know by fitnes value. And as fittnes will be always positive, I set that special case to -1 for visibility. and as i seek for smalest posible autcomes i found that fitnes function good, but i will further investigate this matter.

Comment: The function has no zeros. Also, fitness is negative for everything to the left of the singularity at around `x = 1`.

Comment: Ok, i'm lost. Once agian (and thank you for patient).
So fucntion  (x^5 + x^4+3x^2+x-5) has a zero crossing, also the  1x^5 + x^4-3x^2+x-5 has one. And as fittnes is 1/x and x is always bigger or equal 0, then its always positive.

Comment: As i still sit, and think on what you have writen, and I'm starting to doubt my whole idea, I would be really gratefull if you would sacrifice 15 minuts of your time for a chat about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the minimum value of fitness is -1 (as it means there is no value):

```
public int compareTo(osobnik obj) {
    if (this.fitness == -1 && obj.fitness==-1) //both are equals
        return 0;
    if (this.fitness == -1) // this is the lowest one, so it should return -1
        return 1;
    if (obj.fitness == -1) // obj has the lowest value, so it should return 1
        return -1;
    if (this.fitness > obj.fitness)
        return 1;
    if (this.fitness < obj.fitness)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to treat -1 as the maximum value of fittnes